# MongoDB in Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I was wondering if MongoDB is fully supported in Azure Cosmos DB through the MongoDB API https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-introduction

I have read that the aggregation pipeline, map-reduce and the full-text indexes is not fully integrated. Does anyone have further information about it? Would you use MongoDB in Azure Cosmos DB considering its current status?

Comment: Asking if people would use Cosmos DB is just going to get opinion, discussion, and debate. As for a complete feature-compatibility list: That's not something that exists today.

Answer (score 2):

Cosmos DB implements MongoDB wire protocol and many customers already use MongoDB API in production. Aggregation pipeline is in private preview and you can enable it by emailing askcosmosmongoapi@microsoft.com. Map-reduce functionality is mostly covered by aggregation pipiline. Full-text search is partially available through Azure Search, which can index MongoDB collections and $regex operator within MongoDB API covers less complex text search. You can find some other feature requests and their status at https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/category/321994-mongodb-api

Answer (score 2):

Cosmos DB's MongoDB layer implements a large subset of native MongoDB functionality. Specifics of supported features are published [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-feature-support).

You mentioned aggregation pipeline: As of November 2017, this is now supported.

Regarding "current status" of the Cosmos DB MongoDB API: It's a production database with SLA. You'll need to make your own decision on whether to use it, based on feature set and your app's needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can activate aggregation pipeline through Azure portal by going to Preview Features menu.

[image: Azure portal - Aggregation pipeline]